# Why cant value passed to [(ngModel)] variable appear as a selected value from the PrimeNG drop Down?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am passing the data from parent to child component and the normal text input is populated which the data received from the parent but this isn't working with the dropdowns.

Code block where I pass data to the variable **enteredName** is working just as I want it to work.

```
        <span class="p-float-label">
          <input #nameID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="enteredName" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [textContent]="name" id="nameID"
            maxlength="256" name="nameID" pInputText required type="text" />
          <label for="nameID">Name</label>
        </span>
```

But when I pass the "**selectedRecorderType**" it dosent appear as the option selected from the dropdown.

Below is the code for it.

```
        <span class="p-float-label">
          <p-dropdown [options]="recorderType" name="recorderTypeID" id="recorderTypeID" optionLabel="name"
            [autoDisplayFirst]="false" #recorderTypeID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedRecoderType"
            [disabled]="(!userCanAdd && !userCanModify)" (onChange)="onChangeRecorderType($event)" [required]=true [style]="{'width': '100%'}" appendTo="body">
          </p-dropdown>
          <label for="recorderTypeID">Recorder Type</label>
        </span>
```

Below is the component TS File
I changed the variable from "**selectedRecorder**" to "**selectedRecoderType**", but then I am still with the same problem.
Can I know what wrong am I doing.

**P.S I have updated the Screenshot below as well.**

```
        this.enteredName = "hey";
        this.selectedRecoderType = "Hello";
```

**EDIT**

this.enteredName = "hey";
this.selectedRecoderType = "HELLO";

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO7RM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO7RM.png)]

Comment: In the template you have `selectedRecorderType` but your TS shows `selectedRecorder`, not the same.

Comment: Also, "Hello" needs  to exist within the list of options (which is `recorderType`) for `p-dropdown` automatically show it as selected value.

Comment: @Patrick and l I have made the changes and the edited the question, but still I can't figure out what mistak am I making.

Comment: @Nehal I have made the changes and the edited the question, but still I can't figure out what mistak am I making

Comment: You still didn't address what's inside `recorderType` that is being passed as options to `p-dropdown` -> `<p-dropdown [options]="recorderType" ...`

Comment: @Nehal [options]="recorderType" has array of strings which are responsible for populating the dropdown list

Comment: And what are those strings inside [options]="recorderType"? Is "Hello" one of them?

Comment: @Nehal no HELLO is a dummy data

Comment: There is your answer why it's not showing. `p-dropdown` will match the value from `ngModel` only if that same value exists within the list of options given to it.

Comment: In my case, I removed dataKey from the p-dropdown properties and it worked, I don't even understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding selectedRecoderType  value into recorderType?
eg :recorderType=[{name:'Hello'}];
selectedRecoderType = {name:'Hello'};

Answer (score 0):

Without doing this with an array of strings, why not use objects?

This is a working example of what you need:

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface RecorderTypes {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  enteredName: string;
  recorderTypes: RecorderTypes[];
  selectedRecorderType: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.recorderTypes = [
      { name: 'Test', code: 'Test' },
      { name: 'Hello', code: 'Hello' },
      { name: 'Hello2', code: 'Hello2' },
    ];

    this.enteredName = 'hey';
    this.selectedRecorderType = 'Hello';

  }
}
```

Template HTML:

```
<span class="p-float-label">
  <input
    #nameID="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="enteredName"
    [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
    [textContent]="name"
    id="nameID"
    maxlength="256"
    name="nameID"
    pInputText
    required
    type="text"
  />
  <label for="nameID">Name</label>
</span>

<span class="p-float-label p-mt-5">
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="recorderTypes"
    optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="code"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedRecorderType"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
  <label for="recorderTypeID">Recorder Type</label>
</span>
```

Stackbliz Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c1zxhy?file=src/app/app.component.html